# Giving read permission for group doesn't work

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod

I am trying to learn how the file permission system works. I have a group with `group common`. Then I created 2 accounts; bob and alice with `useradd -m -G common bob/alice`. I have created a password for them both. Then I switched user to alice with `su alice` and created a directory `mkdir shared`. Then I change the ownership `chgrp common shared` and permission for this folder `chmod 740 shared`. Now when I test it I can access the directory with alice. However, when I switch user to bob and try to access the folder it says `bash: cd: shared/: Permission denied`. What am I doing wrong? The members of the group should all have read permission.

Comment: please set the permission to __750__ to allow group searches. let me know how it goes

Comment: It works. However, I don't know why. Shouldn't read permission be enough?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a quirk of UNIX.

To do `ls` on a directory, you need to have execute permission on the directory.

If you only have read permission, you can access the files in the directory but you have to know about them first! e.g.

As Alice:

```
echo "Hello Bob" > shared/hello
```

As Bob:

```
cat shared/hello
```

If you want Bob to be able to `ls` (or `cd` to) the common directory:

```
chmod 750 shared
```

Comment: I'll but I can't now as I have to wait for 4 minutes.... :(

Answer (score 0):

Please note the following about permissions in linux:

- (r) read allows opening a file given its name
- (w) write allows creating files
- (x) execute allows listing or searching files.

So you need to make the permission the folder this **750** for the other user to access it, and because it was created by Alice she has **r,w,x** on but since the permission now is **740** bob won't be able to access it.